# Exporting Results from Linear Optimization in PuLP to Excel

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm new to Python and the PuLP package in general, and have some results in the terminal of my Jupyter Notebook I'd like to export to Excel if possible. I did not create a data frame initially-- but was wondering if it is possible to create a data frame for results after they have printed. My output is below:

```
Service_('CZe_0004',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0004',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0005',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0006',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0007',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0008',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0009',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 87.14
Service_('CZe_0010',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0010',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0011',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0012',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0013',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0014',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 94.76
Service_('CZe_0015',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0015',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0016',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 84.73
Service_('CZe_0017',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'MFC_IL_ROMEOVILLE') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0017',_'MFC_SC_GREER') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0018',_'DC_CA_FRESNO') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0018',_'DC_IN_GREENWOOD') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0018',_'DC_PA_CHAMBERSBURG') = 142.46
Service_('CZe_0018',_'DC_TX_DALLAS') = 0.0
Service_('CZe_0018',_'MFC_FL_JACKSONVILLE') = 0.0
```

I believe I have saturated my search attempts and simply don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a data frame to do this, unless you have another purpose for the data frame.  I think it is just as easy to write out the results to a datafile and use that.

I'd suggest just writing your own "CSV" files (comma separated value).  It is a standard format and fairly universal.  Excel can read them just fine, and they are easier to read back into python.

Here is a little script that makes a fake `pulp` problem and writes the values to a .csv.

If you haven't done it before in Excel, it will open the .csv fine but when you go to save it will give you some options to either re-save it as a .csv with some hideous warnings about formatting, or just saving it as a new .xlsx file.  Your pick.

```
import pulp

sources = ['cze1', 'cze2', 'cze3']
destinations = ['Jax', 'Fresno', 'Dallas']

prob = pulp.LpProblem('example')
service = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('service', [(s, d) for s in sources for d in destinations])

# assign some bogus values (simulate solving...)
for (s, d) in service.keys():
    service[s,d].setInitialValue(1.5)

# write to a csv file
output_filename = 'output.csv'

# use a context manager to open/close the file...
with open(output_filename, 'w') as fout:
    for (s, d) in service.keys():
        line = ','.join([s, d, str(service[s,d].value())])   # make a string out of the elements, separated by commas
        fout.write(line)    # write the line to the file
        fout.write('\n')    # add a newline character
```